# How to AutoHeight CollectionView items in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to display a list of 2 products on 1 row. I use CollectionView set ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2"--> This looks fine. However I don't want to show the extra whitespace of the CollectionView when scrolling down. I have learned about AutoHeight CollectionView however it is not working properly, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c04eec5-986a-4d91-82f2-1cb2a3d8c8c7/how-to-fit-the-height-of-collectionview-when-it-is-wrapped-by-scrollview?forum=xamarinforms).

[image]

```
<Label Text="#Title Test"></Label>
<CollectionView SelectionMode="None" ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductInfos}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Padding="7" HasShadow="False" IsClippedToBounds="True" BackgroundColor="#fff">
                <StackLayout x:DataType="model:ProductInfo">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Frame Padding="0" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="7" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Image WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding Images}">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type locals:DashboardsViewModel}},
                                Path=ProductTappedView}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,15,0" FontSize="12" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#333"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

How can I remove the space below the CollectionView? Or is there any solution instead of CollectionView? Thank you

Comment: Hi! And what do you want to be on that white space? If you scale up your items, they will not show completely (they will be cropped).

Comment: Yes, I want that space to disappear, when I expand the item the height will be auto. I don't want fixed Height. As in my image above, when I scroll down it has excess white space it's very weird

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. When there isn't enough content to fill a page, there should be white space at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I'm trying to handle it. Thank you

Comment: Waiting for your good news.